# prevent mega menu items from automatically be hidden on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So i'm making a web page and i have this mega menu that  when i hover it opens it's items but when i hover on the items it will be hidden.

anyways here's the HTML code:

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown megaDropdown">
  <a href="#" class=" nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Activities<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
    <li class="col-md-12">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme navbar-carousel">
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <img src="assets/01.png" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-navitem">
              Jump
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <img src="assets/01.png" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-navitem">
              Climb
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <img src="assets/01.png" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-navitem">
              Leap
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <img src="assets/01.png" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-navitem">
              Slide
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <img src="assets/01.png" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-navitem">
              Zip n'Trail
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <img src="assets/01.png" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-navitem">
              Skate n'Ride
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And here's the CSS code i set to mage the mega menu trigger on hover:

```
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
```

}

So any of you guys can help me to prevent mega menu items to be disappeared when trying to hover on them.

**and again the mega menu trigger on hover not on click**

Best Regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css into your style and it should stay visible when you hover on the items. Unless there is a gap between them. If so, let me know.

```
.dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: There's is actually!